# Hint needed on last Spirit of Arkham (Arkham Asylum)

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I'm trying to find the last Spirit of Arkham in Batman, Arkham Asylum, but I am totally stumped. I have otherwise completed the game 100% (including the challenges) and this seems to be the last thing left to do.

It seems like I am supposed to find a person and from the previous clues, I am fairly sure that person is

> Warden Sharp.

However, I have not seen them in ages and I have no idea where they might be. I feel like I have spent several hours now combing every inch of the island and all of the buildings, spoken to every living person I can find, but no luck.

I would very much prefer a subtle hint, rather than a heavy spoiler, just to set me in the right direction. I have a couple of questions in particular that I would really like answers to, so perhaps we could just start with these for now?:

1. What is it I actually need to do, once I find the correct person? Do I just need to talk to them, or is there more required than that?
2. Am I correct that it is

> Warden Sharp?

If so, is there any subtle clue you can give me as to where they can be found?

Thanks in advance (again, please no heavy spoilers)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check the room where you last encountered him?

> It is in the Central control room (The last place you see the warden) You will see a smaller round room lined with computers on desks, there is also a bunch of writing on the ground all you need to do is scan that room and you've found it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, it sounds like it is the person I think it is? That location is where I thought I last saw him and I have checked it over a couple of times, but didn't find anything. I will take another look a bit more thoroughly though.

Comment: Ah ok, I've found it now. Thanks again! I thought I was looking for a person - didn't realize I just had to scan the circle on the ground.

Comment: Haha all good. Glad my clue wasn't too cryptic :D